# Why a bullet leaves a hole on glass where stone makes scratch?

Tags: forces, material-science, collision, fracture

When we throw a stone it breaks the glass with scratches. But when a bullet hits the glass it leaves a small hole(not always) . I want to know the specific reason behind making hole and scratch.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136030/

Answer (score 0):

The stone when hits the glass( like wind shield, or a window pane) the impulse is small as the time of contact to the force applied is more.

But for the bullet the time of contact to the force applied to the glass is small so the impulse of the bullet is large.

The glass is not a solid or liquid entirely. the glass is a semi solid or amorphous solid. So it is not easy to predict its behaviour entirely.

The glass used in the vehicles and the one used in the home windows is different. If you hit a stone to the wind shield of the car the glass will not break.

Bullet impact cannot be understood with just the normal laws and the theorm of the solids as there is a special kind of study of the bullet impact called as the terminal balistics.