# A bullet makes a hole but a rock shatters the glass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, inertia

Consider a bullet fired toward a pane of glass. Barring slight cracks, it creates a relatively clean hole in the glass. On the other hand, when a stone is projected toward the same glass pane, it is observed that the glass pane immediately shatters.

I have searched and searched for a convincing answer and the same question even exists on the website "Physics Forum". However, none of the answers are satisfying. Some say that this is due to the greater inertia of the glass against the bullet compared to the smaller inertia of the same against the. Others seem to agree that it is due to the higher momentum(and shorter time) of the bullet.

What is the correct explanation for this?

Comment: Thank you for your question, Kaumudi. Note : (1) The same question already appears on Physics SE : [Can a bullet shot through a glass make a clean hole?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136030). Pease check for duplicates before posting your question. (2) Merely saying "none of the answers are satisfying" is not helpful. In what way are they "not satisfying"? We expect you to give reasons based on physical principles.

Comment: BTW momentum and inertia are the same thing. So greater momentum and greater inertia are the same reason for the absence of cracks.

Comment: They are not satisfying in that they don't address that aspect of the problem that I am facing in understanding this situation, which is that I don't understand this in terms of inertia. (I already did check the question that you have linked but the answers address the structure of the *glass* and not the physics of the question). And how is momentum and inertia the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as one object impacts another, a pressure wave starts to propagate - this wave "tells the object" that it has been hit.

Now the peak value of the stress is a function of the rate at which the glass is being compressed, and of the rate with which the glass moves. If a region a short distance away "doesn't yet know" about the displacement of the glass at the point of impact, then there is a strong local shear / curvature in the glass. When this strain exceeds the limits of the material (glass) it will fracture. Since the bullet is traveling very fast, the wave has not traveled very far in the glass, and all the displacement is in a very small region.

By contrast, a large rock hitting the glass slowly will cause deflection of the entire surface before the local stress becomes very large. This results in the storage of elastic energy over the entire plate - and once a crack initiates (at the point of highest effective stress: actual stress possibly amplified by a stress concentration factor like a small surface crack or other discontinuity) it will propagate throughout the stretched medium (as the crack tip becomes a stress concentrator, it will propagate into regions of lower stress).

Crack propagation stops when the crack reaches a region with insufficient elastic energy stored. In the case of the bullet, the region where stress had time to build up is small.

In summary, the factors to consider are:

1. The time to reach sufficiently night impact stress
2. The propagation velocity of the stress wave in the glass
3. The crack propagation velocity

Comment: Wow, so does it have absolutely nothing to do with inertia? I realize that the properties of the glass which make the wave travel fast/slow is due to inertia but is it not possible to explain this solely in terms of inertia?

Comment: What is inertia except response to force? Wave propagation is all about inertia - but in this case specifically about how much glass "knows" about the impact. When I have some time I will add to the answer - there is another interesting fact about the direction of stress (which indirectly relates to inertia).

Comment: Okay. This example was used as an application of Newton's first law in my textbook. Can you explain why?

Comment: My textbook explains it like this: "The speed of the bullet is very high. Due to its *large inertia of motion*, it cuts a clean hole through the glass. When the stone is thrown, its inertia is much lower so it cannot cut through the glass". Whet do they mean to say by this? Please help.

Comment: I think they mean "when the bullet feels the glass it doesn't slow down very much but keeps going so it can cut a hole." But really that is a simplification of the processes - because a very heavy rock also "keeps going" (if product of mass and velocity for the two is the same). So then it comes down to the rise time of the stress, stress propagation and crack initiation. Which is not as simple as the book makes it out to be.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the impulse of the bullet is less than that of the stone. $J=F\,dt$. But, in the case of a bullet, dt is very small due to its high speed. Thus, it is able to impart its momentum to only a small area thus creating a neat hole. But the stone has a velocity much less than the bullet. Thus, dt is greater. It gets **more time to impart** its momentum and that too over a larger  area. This shatters the glass.

Comment: Oh, this has absolutely nothing to do with the inertia of the glass?